# How to collect data from Firestore in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm working on a small chat project in Angular. And so far I have had problems with using Firestore. Especially with the typescript that I'm learning now.

In app.module.ts, I am initializing the app with

in app.module.ts I am initializing app with

```
    import { provideFirebaseApp, getApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
    import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
    
imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
],
```

Then I made FirestoreService to retrieve and update data.

Methods for updating arrays in my documents work fine, but I can't get data from firestore; it always returns undefine and nothing is returned.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  Firestore,
  getFirestore,
  provideFirestore,
  collectionData,
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  docData,
  query,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
  addDoc,
  firestoreInstance$,
  DocumentData,
  arrayRemove,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
// import { Observable } from '@firebase/util';
import { ProfileUser } from '../model/profile-user';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { from, of, switchMap, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { arrayUnion } from '@firebase/firestore';


constructor(
    private firestore: Firestore,
    private aF: AngularFirestore // twis was added while I was testing other approach found on google
    
  ) { }

async rejectFriendRequest(rejectedUser: string, currentUser: string){
    const recipientRef = doc(this.firestore, "users", JSON.stringify(currentUser));

    await updateDoc(recipientRef, {
      invitationsFrom: arrayRemove(rejectedUser),
      rejectedInvitation: arrayUnion(rejectedUser)
    });
  }
```

The rejectFriendRequest method is working and updating the array in the specified document.
But I can't get documents from Firestore, and I'm not sure what library to use at this point.
And the first idea was to use email addresses for the ID of a document, but that would not work because, when updating, it couldn't find an ID with a "." in it.

This is one of the approaches I have used:

```
async getUser(id: string) {

    var usersRef = this.aF.collection("users").doc(id);

    var colRef = collection(this.firestore, "users")
    var docreference = await doc(colRef, id);

    docData(docreference).subscribe( (result) => {
      console.log(result);
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe the document for changes, you'll need to set  the document reference and the `valueChanges()` method on that reference inside your `constructor` so that you can create an `update` method which can update the item reference as it changes.

This approach would probably be good so all your methods can access it on `this` [Official example docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ (item | async)?.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;
  item: Observable<Item>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/1');
    this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
  }
  update(item: Item) {
    this.itemDoc.update(item);
  }
}
```

Minimal changes in your situation in order to see information should be something along the lines of:

```
const itemDoc = this.firestore.doc(`users/${documentId}`);
const item = itemDoc.valueChanges();
console.log('item', item);
```

The 2nd Firestore defined in your constructor seems odd and like it should not be there so I would try to look at the [examples](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it is appreciated. But I tried the method you proposed, and the result is null, so I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.
-EDIT: It worked if I passed the id as follows: this.aF.collection('users').doc(JSON.stringify(id));
It works, but aF.collection('users').doc(id); does not.
returns undefined with no results.

If I replace "id" with a hardcoded string, it's not working either.

Comment: I apologize I think that information may have been outdated. Revising with information from (https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#streaming-document-data)

Comment: I went through it, and now fetching, updating, and creating operations work for me; I can't give you points, but I appreciate it :)